# RESTful angularjs image post with C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, angularjs, rest

I am new on both AngularJs and Asp.Net Restful services. For a long time, I am trying to post an image data to my web service but I could not succeed in. Here is my code, what am I doing wrong?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <script src="../client/js/angular/data/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../client/js/angular/data/angular-resource.js"></script>
    <script src="../client/js/angular/data/angular-files-model.min.js"></script>
    <title>Image Upload</title>
</head>
<body ng-app="fuApp">
    <div ng-controller="fuAppCtr">
        <table border="1">
            <tr>
                <td><input type="file" ng-files-model="fileModel"></td>
                <td>{{ fileMessage }}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><button ng-click="submit()">Save</button></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    <script>
        var fuApp = angular.module('fuApp', ['ngResource', 'angular-files-model']);
        fuApp.controller('fuAppCtr', function fuAppCtr($scope, $resource, $http) {
            $scope.submit = function () {
                if ($scope.fileModel == null) {
                    $scope.fileMessage = "File is empty!";
                }
                else {
                    var file = $scope.fileModel;
                    var dataObj = {
                        image: file[0]
                    };

                    var res = $http.post("http://localhost:10160/UserService/SaveImage", dataObj);
                    res.success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                        $scope.fileMessage = "Succeed";
                    });
                    res.error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                        $scope.fileMessage = "Failure : " + JSON.stringify({ data: data });
                    });
                }
            }
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>

**C# Code**
[OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, UriTemplate = "SaveImage")]
    string PostViaByteArray(byte[] imgBytes);
```

I get the following fileMessage output on {{ fileMessage }} line;

> The server encountered an error processing the request. The exception
>   message is 'There was an error deserializing the object of type
>   System.Byte[]. End element 'root' from namespace '' expected. Found
>   element 'image' from namespace ''.'. See server logs for more details.
>   The exception stack trace is:
>
> at
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializer.ReadObjectHandleExceptions(XmlReaderDelegator
>   reader, Boolean verifyObjectName, DataContractResolver
>   dataContractResolver)  at
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.DataContractJsonSerializer.ReadObject(XmlDictionaryReader
>   reader, Boolean verifyObjectName)  at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.SingleBodyParameterDataContractMessageFormatter.ReadObject(Message
>   message)  at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.SingleBodyParameterMessageFormatter.DeserializeRequest(Message
>   message, Object[] parameters)  at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DemultiplexingDispatchMessageFormatter.DeserializeRequest(Message
>   message, Object[] parameters)  at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.UriTemplateDispatchFormatter.DeserializeRequest(Message
>   message, Object[] parameters)  at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.DeserializeInputs(MessageRpc&
>   rpc)  at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.InvokeBegin(MessageRpc&
>   rpc)  at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage5(MessageRpc&
>   rpc)  at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage31(MessageRpc&
>   rpc)  at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc.Process(Boolean
>   isOperationContextSet)

Comment: any errors? traceback? what is the problem ?